# Detecting profile picture change on Facebook

Tags: facebook

Is there any way to find out if a user has changed his/her profile picture since a time given? I mean, is there a proper way to achieve that using Facebook API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to store image id when user registers and later with CRON do a query to see if current profile picture id is the same id as one stored, if different then used changed the profile picture.

Second solution is to have access to user feed and from there to check if profile picture was changed, also CRON will be used.

Note: if you plan to use user picture in your app there is no need to check if picture was changed, facebook will always send you the current one.

Comment: I'd like the option of not downloading the profile picture if it's not necessary for simple reasons of bandwidth and data charges in my country.

Comment: For solutions displayed above there is no need of download the picture. Please add more details about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should check [ETags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/etags-reference/). It is some kind of has witch you get in response header. You should store that value and send it next time you make request for image. If image was not changed you will get 304 - Not Modified response from Facebook API.

If you do not want to download images from Facebook you should use `?redirect=false` paramter in Facebook image request (eg. `https://graph.facebook.com/<username>/picture?redirect=false`). This will return json data of profile picture instead of returning the whole image.